# Find the instantiation of a class for a type

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle/HOL, how do I find where a given type was instantiated for a given class? For the sake of this post for example, where `real` was instantiated as a `conditionally_complete_linorder`. To justify the question: I might want to know this for inspiration for a similar instantiation, for showing it to someone(s), for Isabelle/HOL practice reading, for curiosity, and so on. My process at the moment:

First, check it actually is: type `instantiation real :: conditionally_complete_linorder begin end` and see if I get the error message "No parameters and no pending instance proof obligations in instantiation."

Next, ideally before *where* I'd need to know *how* i.e. whether it was direct, or implicit via classes `C_1`[, `C_2`, `C_3`, etc]. Then, I would need to find where those instantiations are, either an explicit `instantiation real :: conditionally_complete_linorder` or the implicit ones for the `C_i` (same process for either case ofc). I don't know how to find out how, so I have to check for an explicit instantiation, then all possible implicit instantiations.

For explicit, I can do a `grep -Ern ~/.local/src/Isabelle2019 -e 'instantiation real :: conditionally_complete_linorder'` (and hope the whitespace isn't weird, or do a more robust search :)). Repeat for AFP location. Alternatively, to stay within the jEdit window:

1. I can find where the class itself was defined by typing `term "x::'a::conditionally_complete_linorder"` then Ctrl-clicking the class name, and then check if `real` is directly instantiated in that file with Ctrl-f.
2. I could then check if it's instantiated where the type `real` is defined by typing `term "x::real"` and Ctrl-clicking `real`, then Ctrl-f for `conditionally_complete_linorder` in that file.

(If it is in either place it'll be whichever is further down in the import hierarchy, but I find just going through those two steps simpler.) However, if neither two places turn it up then either, for whatever reason, it is explicitly instantiated somewhere else or is implicitly instantiated. For that reason `grep` is more robust.

If explicit turns nothing up then I check implicit. Looking at the `class_deps` graph I can see that `conditionally_complete_linorder` can follow from either `complete_linorder` or `linear_continuum`. I can then continue the search by seeing if `real` is instantiated as either of them (disregarding any I happen to know `real` can't be instantiated as). I can also check to see if it's instantiated as both `conditioanlly_complete_lattice` and `linorder`, which is what I can see `conditionally_complete_linorder` is a simple (no additional assumptions) combination of*. Repeat for all of these classes recursively until the instantiations are found. In this case, I can see that `linear_continuum_topology` implies `linear_continuum`, so kill two birds with one stone with `grep -Ern ~/.local/src/Isabelle2019 -e "instantiation.*real" | grep continuum` and find `/path/to/.local/src/Isabelle2019/src/HOL/Real.thy:897:instantiation real :: linear_continuum`.

This process is quite tedious. Less but still quite tedious** would be to get the `class_deps` graph up and Ctrl-f for "instantiation real"  in `Real.thy` and look for instantiations of: the original class, the superclasses of it, or the classes which imply it. Then in the files each those classes are defined search for "instantiation real". Do this recursively till done. In this case I would have found what I needed in `Real.thy`.

Is there an easier way? Hope I just missed something obvious.

* I can't Ctrl-click in `Conditionally_Complete_Lattices.thy` to jump to `linorder` directly, I guess because of something to do with it being pre-built, so I have to do the `term "x::'a::linorder"` thing again.

** And also less robust, as it is minus grep-ing which can turn up weirder instantiation locations, then again I'm not sure if this ever comes up in practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the theory in the code listing below and then use the command `find_instantiations`. I will leave the code without further explanation, but please feel free to ask further questions in the comments if you need further details or suspect that something is not quite right.

```
section ‹Auxiliary commands›
theory aux_cmd
  imports Complex_Main
  keywords "find_instantiations" :: thy_decl  
begin

subsection ‹Commands›

ML ‹

fun find_instantiations ctxt c =
  let
    val {classes, ...} = ctxt |> Proof_Context.tsig_of |> Type.rep_tsig;
    val algebra = classes |> #2 
    val arities = algebra |> Sorts.arities_of;
  in  
    Symtab.lookup arities c
    |> the
    |> map #1
    |> Sorts.minimize_sort algebra
  end

fun find_instantiations_cmd tc st = 
  let
    val ctxt = Toplevel.context_of st;
    val _ = tc 
      |> Syntax.parse_typ ctxt 
      |> dest_Type 
      |> fst 
      |> find_instantiations ctxt 
      |> map Pretty.str 
      |> Pretty.writeln_chunks
  in () end

val q = Outer_Syntax.command
  \<^command_keyword>‹find_instantiations› 
  "find all instantiations of a given type constructor"
  (Parse.type_const >> (fn tc => Toplevel.keep (find_instantiations_cmd tc)));

›


subsection ‹Examples›

find_instantiations filter
find_instantiations nat
find_instantiations real

end
```

---

Remarks

- I would be happy to provide amendments if you find any problems with it, but do expect a reasonable delay in further replies.
- The command finds both explicit and implicit instantiations, i.e. it also finds the ones that were achieved by means other than the use of the commands `instance` or `instantiation`, e.g. inside an ML function.
- Unfortunately, the command does not give you the location of the file where the instantiation was performed - this is something that would be more difficult to achieve, especially, given that instantiations can also be performed programmatically. Nevertheless, given a list of all instantiations, I believe, it is nearly always easy to use the in-built search functionality on the imported theories to narrow down the exact place where the instantiation was performed.